# Bash: while read line "or every 60s"

Tags: bash, read

How do I implement the "or every 60s" in the following example?

```
prints_output_in_random_intervals | \
while read line "or every 60s"
do
  do_something
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Built-in bash documentation `help read` mentions:

```
-t timeout  time out and return failure if a complete line of input is
            not read withint TIMEOUT seconds.  The value of the TMOUT
            variable is the default timeout.  TIMEOUT may be a
            fractional number.  If TIMEOUT is 0, read returns success only
            if input is available on the specified file descriptor.  The
            exit status is greater than 128 if the timeout is exceeded
```

Since `read` will fail if it returns because the timeout is reached,
such a condition will also cause your loop to exit. If you want to
avoid this, you can ignore `read`'s exit status like this:

```
while read -t 60 line || true; do
    ...
done
```

or

```
while true; do
    read -t 60 line
    ...
done
```

Comment: Or move the `read` inside the `while` loop and loop over some other variable or condition.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to break the output. I want Bash to call `do_something` whenever any of these conditions is meet. So when either `prints_output_in_random_intervals` produces some output or 60s have passed.